Maui hot reload is not working for my project. How do I troubleshoot?
I'm trying to figure out why hot reload is not working for my project. My project is pretty simple but I can't figure out why hot reload won't work.
When I create a new MAUI project, hot reload works well. So it's not about a setting in Visual Studio. There must be something in my project that's breaking the hot reload.
This is what I get when I run the app in windows. See the last icon to the right. That's supposed to be the hot reload icon. But it seems like it's indicating an error. But I don't know what error that is. I already resolved all warnings and xaml binding issues. When I click on the icon it just brings me to the hot reload documentation.

And this is what I see when I make a change and click on the hot reload button. It tells me that changes were successfully applied but I don't see those changes in the UI.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

It says hot reload is not supported in WinUI in the first line of your error

Why would it not be supported while in a new project, it can do hot reload? Thanks for pointing that out. I did not see that.

Well the new project that you are running must be in .NET 8, is your old project .NET 8 as well?

My project is also .NET8

Does the other project also have WinUI?

The other project have win ui too. The answer below fixed my issue. Thanks!

Removing this from the project file fixed the issue.
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <_MauiForceXamlCForDebug>true</_MauiForceXamlCForDebug>
</PropertyGroup>


I've also noticed that it works mainly when I start without debugging - then it shows live preview and control tree, and not as slow as under debugger
